# Как сделать положение в слайдере активным?

Tags: html, css, scss

Я формирую несколько слайдов на одной странице, но картинка по умолчанию задается только на последний слайд последнее фото.

Вот последний слайдер:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот все предыдущие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы понимаете, при выборе кружечка на всех предыдущих слайдерах значение на последним слайдере сбрасывается и он приобретает вид второй картинки.
Мой html:

```
<div class="catalog">
    {% for products, imgs in catalog %}
        <div class="item"> 
            
            <div class="slider-container">
                <div class="menu">
                    {% for img in imgs %}
                    <label for="slide{{img.id}}"></label>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                    {% for img in imgs %}
                    <input id="slide{{img.id}}" type="radio" name="slides" checked>
                    <div class="slide slide-1" style="background-image: url('{{img.image.url}}');"></div>
                    {% endfor %}
            </div>

            <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur asperiores ipsa eos molestias deserunt pariatur et nam, eligendi quo ratione, sapiente animi beatae? Quos cumque exercitationem, tempore reiciendis ad nam!</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Мой css:

```
.catalog {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:black;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;

    

}

.text {
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    
}


img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


.slider-container{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.menu label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: 0 .2em;
  &:hover {
    background: black;
  }
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-size:  auto 130%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: left 0s .75s;
}

[id^="slide"]:checked + .slide {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: left .65s ease-out;
}
```

Думаю, что причина кроется в:

```
[id^="slide"]:checked + .slide {
      left: 0;
      z-index: 100;
      transition: left .65s ease-out;
    }
```

checked захватывает только последнею фотографию, но как исправить эту ситуацию я не знаю...
Буду благодарен, если поможете решить проблему.

Answer (score 0):

После двух дней размышления дошло, что в input name тоже нужно генерироваться имя "таблицы" name = {{product.name}}